# Trigger bootstrap tab based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a multiselect drop down and on selecting a particular tab i need to open the bootstrap tab, I'm able to only display the tab but the content of the tab is displayed only after I click on the tab, can anyone tell me the mistake i'm doing ?

This is my dropdown code

```
 <select name="subrole" id="subrole" class="inversed dropdown multiCheckbx triggerTab" multiple="multiple" ng-model="subrole" 

                                multiselect-dropdown required>

                                         <option value="Actor" class="actor" id="actor" href="Actor"> Actor </option>
                                    <option value="Director" class="director" id="director" href="Director"> Director </option>
                                    <option value="Lyricist" class="lyricist" id="lyricist" href="Lyricist"> Lyricist </option>
                                    <option value="Music Director" class="musicdirector" id="musicdirector" href="MusicDir"> Music Director </option>
                                    <option value="Singer" class="singer" id="singer" href="singer"> Singer </option>
                                    <option value="Standup Comedian" class="standupcomedian" id="standupcomedian" href="standupcomedian"> Standup Comedian </option>

                                </select>
```

This is my script

```
$('.triggerTab').on('change', function(e) {
    //var subbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("last")[0];
    //$(subbtn).show();
    $('#tabscontainer').show();
    var selected = new Array();
    selected = $('.triggerTab').val();
//alert(selected[0]);
if(jQuery.inArray("Singer", selected) !== -1) {

    $($("#myTab").find("li")[0]).show();

}
else {

    $($("#myTab").find("li")[0]).hide();
}
DisplayTab();
```

To display my tabs container i'm using calling the following function DisplayTab() but this displays a particular tab by default and not the selected tab

```
     function DisplayTab() {

var selecteditems = new Array();
selecteditems = $('#subrole').val();
if(selecteditems!==null && selecteditems.length!== 0)
{
            //$('#tab-2').show();
          //  $('#myTabs a[href="#menu2"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
                    $('#tabscontainer').show();


}
else {
            //$('#myTabs a[href="#menu2"]').tab('hide') // Select tab by name
                    $('#tabscontainer').hide();

}
}
```

How do i display a particular tabs content ?

Answer (score 0):

what about this code that checks the number of selected options and then show the tab.

```
if ($("#subrole option:selected").length > 0) {
 // You might need a trigger for the tab
 $('#tabscontainer').trigger('click');
 // or follow your logic if that works
 $('#tabscontainer').show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your solution and it doesn't seem to work. Any idea about how i can use this .trigger('click') for the particular tab ?
      <li class="singer" id="tab-1">
      <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#menu1">SINGER</a>

Comment: I tried $('#tab-1').trigger('click'); but it isn't working

Comment: try the link inside the li, $('#tab-1').find('a').trigger('click');